# How to a add dynamically headers the request in react-admin?

Tags: typescript, react-admin

I'm using `react-admin`, my data provider is `simpleRestProvider`.
I need to add dynamically headers to requests according to user behavior.

Is it possible?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. A very handy place to plug in in the `react-admin`'s pipeline is the `httpClient` which is passed to the dataProvider. [Also shown in the docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#sending-credentials-to-the-api)

```
    import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
    import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

    const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
        if (!options.headers) {
            options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
        }
        const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
        options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
    };
    const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000', httpClient);
```

**Edit:** If you want to pass headers dynamically on each `dataProvider` call, I guess you will have to modify the implementation of the a
`dataProvider` as currently the `ra-data-simple-rest` [package](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest/src/index.ts) doesn't pass receive the `options` param to pass it down to the httpClient but rather creates it internally. You don't have to build this from scratch - just fork the repo and create an enhanced version.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I see this. but this a hard chage, it happen once time and the same for all the requests. I need to add headres more dynamically. inside the componnets.

Comment: I got your point - I haven't figured out a way to this with current dataProvider implementaton. If you want to make it work efficiently in this way and not recreating the dataProvider all the time, you will need a modifed version of the dataProvider - checkout the edit above.

Comment: Thanks!  it seems that is. I wiil check it